# Modify AggregateResult List value to take substring of it for displaying on vfp

Tags: visualforce, soql, controller, list, aggregateresult

**solved: I was able to return them as sObject instead of list since I know I will always receive a single value. I was then able to use right function to take my substring.

Below is my controller I am using  to return the first and last car in the garage. I want to take a substring of the last 5 characters of the firstCar and LastCar I return in the lists and append the shortened value in the list so I can display that on my visualforce page. I have not been able to figure out how to access the list to use .substring function. I appreciate any direction or help.

```
    public String CarId {get;set;}
    public List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList{get;set;}
    public List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList2{get;set;}
    public CarController() {
        
        CarId = ' ';
        
        CarId=System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');
        
        System.debug('...................CarId=='+CarId);
        
        Id i= Id.valueOf(CarId);
        
        AggregateResultList = new List<AggregateResult>();
        AggregateResultList = [SELECT min(Car__c) firstCar FROM Car__c WHERE Garage__c = :i GROUP BY Sequence__c ORDER BY Sequence__c ASC limit 1];
        
        AggregateResultList2 = new List<AggregateResult>();
        AggregateResultList2 = [SELECT max(Car__c) lastCar FROM VIN__c WHERE Garage__c = :i GROUP BY Sequence__c ORDER BY Sequence__c DESC limit 1];   
        
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add a debug line for AggregateResult you'll see its structure if not otherwise obvious from the doc. Then you can use array operators to access individual elements of the list

Comment: Thanks @cropredy. This helped me figure out the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate SOQL returns a list where each list element represents the ith grouped by field.

So, since you are doing MIN and MAX and returning only 1 row, you can get the result from the row

```
aggregateResultList[0].get('firstcar).left(5);
```

Given that you are doing this in VF (and not LWC), here's a pattern I find useful for the VF controller that also addresses your specific issue. I renamed variables and changed their case to conform to conventions.

```
public class CarController {
  public Id carId {
     get {
        if (carId == null) {
            carId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');
         }
         return carId;} set;
   }      
   
   public List<String> firstLastCars {  // displayed on VF page
    get {
       if (firstLastCars == null) {
          firstLastCars = new List<String> {
            [SELECT MIN(Car__c) firstCar 
                FROM Car__c WHERE Garage__c = :this.carId 
                GROUP BY Sequence__c 
                ORDER BY Sequence__c ASC limit 1][0].get('firstCar').left(5),
            [SELECT MAX(Car__c) lastCar 
                FROM VIN__c 
                WHERE Garage__c = :this.carId 
                GROUP BY Sequence__c 
                ORDER BY Sequence__c DESC limit 1][0].get('lastCar').left(5)
           };
        }
        return firstLastCars;
     } private set;
    }
   
    public CarController();
 }
```

I like my constructors to be minimalist and let the logic for sourcing data for the VF page merge fields to be handled by properties which are coded to be lazy loaded (saves on resources) and invokable in non-deterministic order (which is how the VF page invokes getters). Your use case may be simple at the moment but as you evolve this VF controller/page, the pattern proves its worth.

SFDC, of course, recommends LWC for new UX development but not all shops have done the conversion